# Not able to find element in an Integer array

Tags: java, generics

In this code, I am able to find and count any element that's less than 10.
But when it comes to finding an element that is greater than 10 the counter always shows 0, even though the searched element is present in an array. I used generic interface and static methods...
Word counting is working properly, but the problem is with numbers greater than 10, it always shows 0.
Here is the code:

````
 interface FuncCounter<T>{
    int function(T[] t, T tt);
}
class Implementation{
    static<T> int equalValues(T[] t , T tt) {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< t.length; i++) {
            if(t[i]==tt)
                counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
}

public class GenericMethodRef{
    static<T> int countOperation(funcCounter<T> fc , T[] t , T v) {
        return (int) fc.function(t, v);
        
    }
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Integer[] nums = {1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6122,23,4,12,44,12,12,12,44,5,6,32, 318,318,318};
        String[] words = {"one","two","three","four","four","twelve","eleven", "eleven"};
        int countNum = countOperation(Implementation::<Integer>equalValues,nums,6122);
        int countWords = countOperation(Implementation::<String>equalValues,words,"eleven");
        System.out.println("318 presence: " + countNum);
        System.out.println("'eleven' counted: " + countWords);
        
    }```
````

Comment: Just like classes, by convention, Interface names should begin with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you use AutoBoxing on Integers, which turn `int` into `Integer`, and as a reference it will not properly work with the `==` operator.

Instead, use the `.equals()` method, or better yet, the `Objects.equals(t[i], tt)` call.

To add, Integers and Longs and even Strings etc are usually (in most JVMs) stored/hashed for int values from -10 to 10 to point to the IDENTICAL objects (`==` works). So this is why it wrongly works on low numbers but fails on higher numbers.

Comment: Also see @LoveshDongre 's post, he additionally points out that you can override the `.equals()` method in you custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

Remember these 3 rules

1. `==` on primitive data type will compare the actual values
2. `==` on reference data type will compare whether the two objects share the same memory or not
3. `equals()` method for predefined class will compare the actual values for reference datatype. It can be overridden for our own classes.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your method is called equalValues, you don’t use the equals() method, and that’s the problem: you pass an array of Integer, the wrapper class for it. Objects for values smaller than an implementation defined limit are cached, so it works for small numbers. Larger values are not held in the cache and so the identity operator == returns false.

You can fix your code by using Objects.equals(t[i], tt) instead.

Please read up on the difference between == and equals in the Java documentation for more details.